# Continously run Phirehose on EC2 micro instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, background-process, twitter-streaming-api, phirehose

I want to run [Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose), a php Twitter streaming API on Amazon EC2 to run continuously. I used the following code

```
<?php
// TweetStream.php
require_once "OauthPhirehose.php";
require_once "../ajax/common.php";

const table_name = "tweets";

set_time_limit(0);

class Consumer extends OauthPhirehose {
    private $cobj; // mysqli object

    protected $count = 0;

    public function __construct($a, $b, $c) {
        parent::__construct($a, $b, $c);
        $this->cobj = new mysqli(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
    }

    public function enqueueStatus($status) {
        $data = json_decode($status);

        $cond = !isset($data->delete) && !isset($data->warning);
        $cond = $cond && !($data->id == 0 || trim($data->user->name) == "" || trim($data->text) == "" || $data->geo == NULL);
        if($cond) {
            ++$this->count;

            echo str_pad($this->count, 12, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT).": Getting Tweet: ".$data->id_str." Inserting... ";

            $id = $data->id_str;
            $idi = $data->id;
            $user = $data->user->name;
            $coord = $data->coordinates->coordinates;
            $lat = $coord[1];
            $lng = $coord[0];
            $tweet = $data->text;

            $stmt = $this->cobj->prepare("insert into ".table_name." values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssdds", $id, $user, $lat, $lng, $tweet);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->errno) echo "skipped: ".$stmt->error;
            else echo "done. \n";

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}

define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", "******");
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", "******");

define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "******");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "********");

$sc = new Consumer(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, Phirehose::METHOD_SAMPLE);
$sc->setLang("en");
$sc->consume();
?>
```

Once I upload this code to the EC2 instance I open ssh using Putty and execute following commands

```
$ cd /var/www/html/service
$ nohup php TweetStream.php &
```

After 5 minutes or so, when I run `top -p $(pgrep -d',' php)`, I get the following

```
top - 06:38:52 up 1 day,  4:04,  1 user,  load average: 64.61, 66.82, 65.65
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    606528k total,   599552k used,     6976k free,     1172k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    29660k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11902 ec2-user  20   0  438m 9096 1792 S  0.0  1.5   0:06.18 php
```

I can gather that it has run for 6 minutes or so and got into sleep state. Can I please know what am I missing?

How to make this process run continuously on Amazon EC2 Instance? Please help me friends.

By the way, The mysqli is connecting to RDS instance running in Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, running with `screen` instead `nohup` did the trick.
I followed the tutorial here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection